# integral of complex conjugate times the differential is purely imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to figure out why $\int_C\overline{f(z)}f'(z)dz$ is purely imaginary (C is a closed curve).  I was told to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that the real part of the integrand is an exact differential.

I wrote down that $\int_C\overline{f(z)}f'(z)dz = \int_C(u(x,y)-v(x,y))(\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{dv}{dx}) $

The real part of this is $u(x,y)\frac{du}{dx}+v(x,y)\frac{dv}{dx}$.  I can apply the C-R equations, but I don't see how that would make this part dissapear.

EDIT: For clarification, $f(z)$ is analytic in the region in which C lies.

EDIT2: So integrals of exact differentials over closed curves always vanish.  This means that I need to prove that $u(x,y)\frac{du}{dx}+v(x,y)\frac{dv}{dx}$ is a exact differential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the $dz$. Take the real part of the differential $\overline{f(z)}f'(z)\, dz$ to get

$$(uu_x + vv_x)\, dx + (vu_x - uv_x)\, dy.$$

Now since $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$, this differential becomes

$$(uu_x + vv_x)\, dx + (vv_y + uu_y)\, dy = d\left(\frac{u^2 + v^2}{2}\right).$$

Hence $\operatorname{Re}(\overline{f(z)}f'(z)\, dz)$ is exact, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the $dz$ error.  Fixing that easily got me to $(uu_x + vv_x)\, dx + (vv_y + uu_y)\, dy$.  I just don't see how you got the RHS of that equation.  Also, why is that exact?  I was approaching the problem as $(uu_x + vv_x)\, dx = \frac{df}{dx}$ and $(vv_y + uu_y)\, dy = \frac{df}{dy}$ in order to be exact (from the definition of an exact function).

Comment: @Snagglewhen since $(u^2 + v^2)_x = 2uu_x + 2vv_x$ and $(u^2 + v^2)_y = 2uu_y + 2vv_y$, we have $$d\left(\frac{u^2 + v^2}{2}\right) = (uu_x + vv_x)\, dx + (uu_y + vv_y)\, dy.$$ Guessing from what your wrote, you will need to show that $$(uu_x + vv_x)_y = (vv_y + uu_y)_x$$ in order to show that the differential above is exact. But what I wrote directly implies that the differential is exact.